# Delete element from array when a condition match in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

I am iterating through the array in shell script and when condition matches i.e. if found 'b' want to delete  that element from the array.  I am not using the index position to iterate through. My array has values (a b c)

My code is

```
for h in $Arr
do 
    echo -e "Value of current element $h.\n"

    if [ $h == "b" ]
    then
        echo -e "Delete it\n"

    else
        echo -e "Stay here\n"
    fi
done
```

How can I delete 'b' when condition matches so that when I print my array it should print (a c) ??

Answer (score 1):

You could build a temp array `Brr` with the accepted values, then assign `Arr`with its value?

```
Arr=" a b c"
Brr=""
for h in $Arr
do
  echo -e "Value of current element $h.\n"
  if [ $h == "b" ]
  then
    echo -e "Delete it\n"
    #do not add it to Brr
  else
    echo -e "Stay here\n"
    # add it to Brr the temp array
    Brr="${Brr} $h"
  fi
done
Arr="${Brr}"
echo $Arr
```